# Конечные автоматы

Tags: конечные-автоматы, c++

Здравствуйте!
Есть у меня следующий вопрос:

```
struct mylist
{
    char *oldState, symbol, *newState;
    mylist *next;   
};
```

//есть у меня линейный список такого вида, где (oldState, symbol) -> newState
   //это функция перехода от старого состояния к новому (используется в конечных автоматах)

И я хочу сделать структуру дерева так, чтобы по линейному списку образовывались переходы от одного состояния (вершины) до другой вершины (состояния). Как мне это осуществить?

Comment: Как думаете, такой вариант подойдет, тогда подскажите, как обращаться к последнему полю?

struct mytree

    {

        char *state, value;
        mylist *way;
        mytree **way;

    };

Comment: @Berailv

      чтобы по линейному списку образовывались переходы от одного состояния (вершины) до другой вершины (состояния)

Что значит "по линейному списку"? Чего Вы собственно хотите?

Comment: То есть я хочу сделать подобие B-дерева, чтобы из одной вершины могло быть несколько веток; можно было через массивы сделать, но там так громоздко, захотелось этот метод попробовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Beraliv](/users/11612/beraliv)](/users/11612/beraliv), видимо проще всего сделать что-то в таком духе.

```
// структуры графа (gcc/g++)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct link;   // это опережающее объявление структуры

struct node {  // узел графа
  struct node   *next;      // следующий узел в общем списке
  struct link   *branches;  // список переходов
  char *old_state, *new_state, 
    symbol;
};

struct link {  // описание ребра (перехода) в графе
  struct link *next; // следующий переход в списке переходов узла
  struct node *node; // узел к которому переходим
  int  weight;       // вес перехода
};

struct node *Mylist = 0; // список узлов графа

int
main () 
{
  struct link li1, li2;
  struct node node1, node2;

  Mylist = &node1;

  node1.next = node2.next; node2.next = 0;
  node1.branches = &li1;
  li1.next = &li2; li2.next = 0;
  li1.node = &node2; 
}
```

Т.е. добавьте структуру `link` для описания списка переходов к узлу.

Код в main это просто тестик для компиляции.

Однако, не думаю, что с такими простыми структурами можно сделать эффективные алгоритмы для сколь-нибудь большой задачи.

Comment: Ну да, эффективности тут мало. Обращаться к следующему узлу дерева крайне неудобно. Если я уже прошел нужный мне элемент, тогда не очень приятная ситуация, придется возвращаться и выполнять поиск нужной, а это времязатратное дело

Comment: Почему неудобно?

Вот например:


     struct link *prev = 0, *cur = somenode->branches;
     while (cur) {
       do_something(cur);
       if (cur->next)
         do_somethig2(cur->next);
       prev = cur;
       cur = cur->next;
     }

Тут-то все ОК. Избранные точки (указатели) для переборов можно в стек (еще один список) класть. 



Другой вопрос, что за алгориьмы Вы хотите испоьзовать. Вообще задача (цель) какая?

Comment: Я хочу недетерминированный конечный автомат написать, вот первый раз имею с ним дело.
Цель: вводится строка, которая оценивается автоматом, и говорит, принимает его или нет. Автомат задан с помощью древовидной структуры.

Comment: Вот так?

    struct node *cur = Start_state;
    while (get_symbol(&c)) {
      struct link *p = cur->branches;
      while (p) {
        if (p->node->symbol == c) {
          cur = p->node;
          break;
        }
        p = p->next;
      }
      if (!p) {
         msg("bad char",c);
         break;
      }
      if (p == End_state) {
         msg("OK",c);
         break;
      }
    }

что-то такое, наверное, может только `symbol` перенести в struct link?

Comment: Вот ошибка у Хэшкода. Не могу комментировать в том, уезжает большой последной не странице коммент. за край экрана (FFox 12.02).

---

Продолжаю. @Beraliv, если я угадал, то лучше наверное 'symbol` перенести в `link`, т.е. в описание перехода. 

Хотя я не очень понимаю в чем тут недетерминированность?

Comment: А он у меня первоначально был в link, да и у вас можно его вместо weigth использовать, так как вес у ребра - это и есть переход по какому-то символу. Вообще вот у меня такой вариант на нынешний момент, не знаю:

     struct mylist
     {
         char *oldState, symbol, *newState;
         mylist *next, *start;
     };
     
     struct mytree
     {
         char *state;
         mylist *way;
         mytree *root;
     };

И я еще хотел для каждого поля mylist соорудить дерево, однако не знаю, как это реализовать, посмотрел на Ваш пример и в некотором сомнении

Comment: И добавление в дерево на нынешний момент в таком виде:

    void addTree(char *state, mylist *schedule)
    {
        myTree = new mytree();
        myTree->state = state;
        schedule = schedule->start;
        while (schedule)
        {
            if (schedule->oldState == state)
                addList(myTree->way, schedule->oldState, schedule-            >symbol, schedule->newState);
        }
        myTree->root = myTree;
    }

И я вот в замешательстве, как мне лучше сделать такое дерево, и от этого зависеть будет прохождение по нему

Comment: @Beraliv, из Ваших комментариев я понял, что `weight` в данной задаче вообще не нужен.

Видимо Вы описали построение автомата?

В addTree() ошибки. 

1) Вы делаете новый экземпляр `mytree` и просто теряете его здесь. 

2) Зачем-то делаете указатель `root` в нем на себя.

3) В while указатель schedule не меняется

4) В addList() myTree->way видимо передается по ссылке? Вот терпеть не могу таких угадаек. Хотите менять аргумент в функции - передавайте его адрес.

Чтобы Ваши идеи были понятней, поподробней опишите *словами* структуры данных, естественно с комментариями когда какое поле меняется.